# aside placing problem

Tags: html

Im almost done with making the base layout for my site.
You can see it here : http://test.tamarawobben.nl/

but as you can see the right colummn is not on the right place.

Can anyone help me figure ut why this happens.

Roelof

Answer (score 0):

```
#main
{
    float:left;
}
```

That will fix it.  Its current width and float style force the right column down.

Comment: Now tryint o find out why the links are not well placed.